# How do I print out an Instruction in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm

```
for (BasicBlock::iterator i = bb->begin(), e = bb->end(); i != e; ++i) {
    i.print(errs()); ???
```

I am writing an **LLVM PASS** and I want to get the list of instructions inside the basic block, but how do print them out on the console so I can see them? The code above shows the code i have tried, it iterates through every instruction in the basic block but I get the error below for the print function.

> error: ‘llvm::BasicBlock::iterator’ has no member named ‘print’
>       i.print(errs());

Is there a better approach to printing out instructions?

Comment: When posting questions regarding build errors, please include the actual errors you get.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback, I have added the error message i am getting

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that iterators emulate pointers, so you need to use one of the dereference operators to access the "value" in the iterator. Like e.g. `i->print(...)`.

Comment: ah i see, that solves it, thanks a lot

Comment: Since instruction inherits Value class, you can also call [i->dump()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#aea8889367eaa92a9ac20f4737e8bc99e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to print the iterator and not an instruction.  You can try one of the following approaches.  You can print the instructions in a basic block by either printing the basic block or printing each instruction:

```
BasicBlock* bb = ...; // 
errs() << *bb;
for (BasicBlock::iterator i = bb->begin(), e = bb->end(); i != e; ++i) {
  Instruction* ii = &*i;
  errs() << *ii << "\n";
```

Both prints will output the same results.