# How to solve compile error for the llvm example?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

I try to compile the official site example, the [Kaleidoscope](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html) example. 
I totally copy the example and compile with the given command. But I can't compile success.

Here is the error information:
[image: compile error]

After add the #include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h". This error sovled.
Though another error comes out.
[image: link error]

Comment: If you supply the source then it'll be a lot easier for people to help :)

Comment: @splrs The source code is in the [Kaleidoscope](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html) link. You can find it by scrolling down.

Comment: Actually your usage of errs() is wrong, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959551/how-do-i-print-out-an-instruction-in-llvm#comment71125983_41959551

Comment: @deLta you mean the llvm official example is wrong?

Comment: No, that usage is fine.

Comment: You do not have the zlib installed. For ubuntu you would need the package zlib1g-dev. For other distros it is named similar.

Comment: @mkaes Thanks a lot. I have solved it by install zlib.

Answer (score 0):

toy.cpp can't find errs() function.
Try to locate errs() declaration (.h file) and include this file inside toy.cpp

Comment: I can't find where the .h file is.

Comment: Use any system tool to find *.h files or use search over all files to find err()

Comment: It should be in `llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h`

Comment: I have updated the question. You can see the new pic above.@user7491616